# how to send an Excel file to an email using nodemailer module

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using 'nodemailer' module to send an Excel file as an attachment to an email.

Note: What i am passing to 'content' in attachments is an array of objects.

```
 function sendEmailWithAttachments(recipientEmailId, subject, content, next) {

        var ormMailerInfo = getORMMailerInfo();
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            host: ormMailerInfo.orm_mailer_host,
            secure: ormMailerInfo.orm_mailer_secure,
            port: ormMailerInfo.orm_mailer_port,
            auth: {
                user: ormMailerInfo.orm_mailer_user,
                pass: ormMailerInfo.orm_mailer_pass
            }
        }));

        transporter.sendMail({
            from: ormMailerInfo.orm_mailer_user,
            to: recipientEmailId,
            subject: subject,
            attachments: [
                {   /* the uniqueness of my question begins from here */
                    // file being sent is Excel file as '.xlsx' indicates
                    filename: subject + '.xlsx',
                    // content/data being sent an array of objects
                    content: new Buffer(content,'utf-8')
                }
                ]
        }, next);
    }
```

I have successfully sent and received it but when opening the excel file, it displays this error below:

"Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format for the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Any help, dear members ?

Comment: Which OS u r using? Try out with `.csv` extension

Comment: How do you generate the XLSX content? Kind it is not so simple to create a CSV file. Maybe you need to use some library such https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: @ Suresh Prajapati, my OS is Windows 10. I have tried with .csv extension  and the excel file opens well but the data in the file is just   [object Object]       [object Object]

Comment: @ Suresh Prajapati, Sorry, this [object Object] [object Object] was due to this change i made :
content: content.toString()  
but when i used this:
content: new Buffer(content,'utf-8'), 
the file also opens well but no data at all meaning it is just an empty file !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have eventually got 2 ways of solving this and both worked for me:

```
      /*1. using `to-csv` module -> `npm i to-csv`*/
      var toCsv = require('to-csv');
      attachments: [{filename: subject + '.csv',content: toCsv(content)}]

     or

     /* 2. using `json2csv` module -> npm i json2csv*/
     attachments: [{filename: subject + '.csv',content:json2csv(content)}]

       function json2csv(content){
       const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
       var fields = getFields(content);
       return new Parser({ fields }).parse(content);

       function getFields(content){
            var fields = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
                fields = Object.keys(content[i]);
                if(fields.length > 0)
                    break;
            };
            return fields;
        }
        }
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify content as the plain string and convert content to `csv` format with .csv as file extension.

To convert an array of objects to csv formatted string you can use below code and then pass the returned string to your `sendEmailWithAttachments` as `content`.

```js
var isArray = Array.isArray
  , keys = Object.keys;

CSV.CHAR_RETURN = 0xd;
CSV.CHAR_NEWLINE = 0xa;
CSV.DELIMITER = 0x2c;
CSV.CHAR_ENCAPSULATE = 0x22;

function head (a) {
  return a[0];
}

function tail (a) {
  return a[a.length -1];
}

function char (c) {
  return 'number' === typeof c
    ? String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arguments)
    : c;
}

function needsEncapsulation (string) {
  return !!string && (
          string.toString().indexOf(char(CSV.DELIMITER)) >= 0 ||
          string.toString().indexOf(char(CSV.CHAR_RETURN)) >= 0 ||
          string.toString().indexOf(char(CSV.CHAR_NEWLINE)) >= 0 ||
          string.toString().indexOf(char(CSV.CHAR_ENCAPSULATE)) >= 0
        );
}

function encapsulate (string) {
  var wrapperChar = char(CSV.CHAR_ENCAPSULATE)
    , replaceWith = "\\" + char(CSV.CHAR_ENCAPSULATE)
    , escapedValue = string.toString().replace(new RegExp(wrapperChar, 'g'), replaceWith);

  return wrapperChar + escapedValue + wrapperChar;
}

/**
 * Parses an array of objects to a CSV output
 */

// try { module.exports = CSV; } catch(e) {}
function CSV (objects, opts) {
  if ('object' !== typeof objects) throw new TypeError("expecting an array");

  opts = 'object' === typeof opts
    ? opts
    : {};

    objects = isArray(objects)
      ? objects.slice()
      : [objects];

      if (!objects.length) throw new Error("expecting at least one object");

      var headers = keys(head(objects))
        , buf = [];

      while (objects.length) {
        var lbuf = []
          , object = objects.shift();

        for (var i = 0 ;i < headers.length; ++i) {
          var header = headers[i];

          if (lbuf.length) lbuf.push(char(CSV.DELIMITER));
          object[header] = needsEncapsulation(object[header])
            ? encapsulate(object[header])
            : object[header];

            lbuf.push(object[header]);
        }

        buf.push(lbuf.join(''));
        buf.push(char(CSV.CHAR_RETURN, CSV.CHAR_NEWLINE));
      }

      return false !== opts.headers
        ? [].concat(headers.join(char(CSV.DELIMITER)), char(CSV.CHAR_NEWLINE)).concat(buf).filter(Boolean).join('')
        : buf.filter(Boolean).join('');
}


var data = [];
 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    data.push({ 
        id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2), 
        value: data.length % 2 
    });
}
 
console.log(CSV(data));
```

The above code is taken from [to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-csv) module.

To specify `text/plain` in attachemt setting use `contentType` property

```
attachments: [
  {   
    filename: 'youfile_name.csv',
    content: yourContent,
    contentType: 'text/plain'
  }
]
```

Let me know in case you are facing any issue.

Comment: @CCC did u try `npm i to-csv` first?

Comment: @CCC seems some problem with your code. Can you add your code and update the question?

Comment: ok good. but doing npm i to-csv eliminates the need for your function posted because these 2 lines did the job as expected:
var toCsv = require('to-csv');
toCsv(content);

Comment: @CCC Yes, either use that package or use that code in your project, both will solve the issue.