# Sending an email with an Excel file as an attachment (nodemailer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email to a user with the nodemailer library. However, I also need to send an Excel file (.xlsx) as an attachment. I've had some success sending a .csv file, but I need to send it as an .xlsx.
Here's my code so far

```
import xlsx from 'xlsx';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import os from 'os';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs-extra';

const mail = 'testmail@something.com';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({...});

const wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
wb.Props = { Title: 'Excel', Subject: 'Excel' };
wb.SheetNames.push('Excel');
const wData = [['Some','Data']];
const ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(wData);
wb.Sheets['Excel'] = ws;
const wbout = xlsx.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

const fileName = '${mail}_${Date.now()}.xlsx';
const tempFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
await fs.writeFile(tempFile, wbout);

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'johndoe@test.com',
  to: mail,
  subject: 'Excel',
  attachments: {
    filename,
    content: wbout,
    path: tempFile
  }
};

return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

So far I haven't been able to send it as intended, so can you guys help me?
Also, I've tried looking at:
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441482/how-to-send-an-excel-file-to-an-email-using-nodemailer-module)

However, they seem to base their solutions on sending the file as a .csv, something I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggles and in my case what worked was setting the `contentType` to 'application/octet-stream':

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: this.sender,
    to: this.recipient,
    subject: "report",
    text: "report",
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: 'report' + '.xlsx',
            content: Buffer.from(buffer),
            contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        }
    ],
    headers: {'x-myheader': 'test header'}
};
```